# Big O notation 2^log(n) equals what Big O and can something be greater

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, proof, coding-efficiency

I am trying to figure out if `f(n) = O(g(n))`.

I understand that:

```
O(g(n)) = { f(n) there exists constants c, n0 > 0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c × g(n) for all n ≥ n0 }
```

So I have:

```
f(n) = 2^(logn)
g(n) = n^1000
```

I understand that `f(n)` most closely resembles `O(n)` usually. However it is less than `g(n)` therefore would the proof hold true even though the Big O is much much larger than expected?

Comment: Big O is not precise. It's an upper bound. Saying that f is in O(g) just means that f is not worse than g. If you know enough to express a precise asymptotic bound, you can use ["Θ(g)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science) ("Big theta").

Answer (score 0):

If

```
f(n) = n
g(n) = n^1000
```

then `f = O(g)`. Broadly, if `f=O(g)` and `h` is "bigger" than `g`, then `f=O(h)`.

But there's a catch here:

```
f(n) = 2^(logn)
```

This `log` has what base? Ordinarily We write something like `O(logn)` and we don't care about the base; O(log<sub>2</sub>n) and O(log<sub>99</sub>n) are the same thing, because log<sub>a</sub>n = k log<sub>b</sub>n, where `k` is constant. But what is 2<sup>log<sub>b</sub>n</sup>?

```
2^(logb n) = 2^((log2 n)(logb 2))
           = (2^(log2 n))^(logb 2)
           = n^(logb 2)
```

How does that compare to n<sup>1000</sup>?
Suppose:

```
b = 2^(1/2000)  (just slightly more than 1)
2 = b^2000
logb 2 = 2000
```

So in some cases, it is not true that 2<sup>logn</sup> = O(n<sup>1000</sup>).